# What offer did Devaraj give to Saaho?

Tags: plot-explanation, saaho

In [*Saaho* (2019)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saaho), Roy says to Devaraj, who has been using Saaho to steal vault from 
Devaraj and Prince towers:

> Roy: **You gave Saaho an offer** But Saaho gave me a bigger offer than
>   that. He gave me back my Black Box. I'm giving him back what he wants.

What offer did Devaraj give to Saaho?